# jQuery post result Differs from php output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

All of a sudden, jQuery posts are causing me a problem.

When I issue

```
 $.post ('Calendar01.php',{month:$date},function ($result){
    console.log ('result = ' + $result);
    alert ('result = ' + $result);
 })
```

the result in both the alert and on the console are as they should be, they report the date that was passed to `Calendar01.php`.

The simple PHP in `Calendar01` looks like this

```
if (isset ($_POST ['month']))
    $date = $_POST['month'];
else $date = '2015-01-01';

echo 'PHP Date = '.$date;
```

`Calendar01.php` does **not** receive the date information that is passed as is evidenced by the fact that it always echos the date as 2015-01-01.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe ```$date``` is empty? Did you check that first. Sometimes we're so focused at one place that we forgot some simple things so I prefer asking first! When I come across this kind of issue, I test using a REST Client. You select your HTTP Method, the host/path and the Request Parameters. In this case, you'd add the parameter  'month' and you'd get the "raw" result from ```Calendar01.php```. You can achieve this using the Google Chrome Debug Tools too, in the "Network" section, e.g.: http://sht.tl/9XJhnX

Comment: Nope, date is not empty.  For testing I hard code it just to make certain.  Firebug is seeing the correct date as being posted.  

I'll keep plugging way.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways but I'll give you one of then:

1) Use Firefox

2 Install firebug addon - this is your best friend so you need it

3) open Firebug pressing F12 on your test page

4) submit your request

5) check the Net tab for what you really sending

Then decide what's really happend :) I'm sure you are not sending 'month' as you think. But no code is given how you set your variable you sending through your Ajax request.

Comment: and one more thing ... It is assumed as a good style to define a variavle starting with a $ sign, when this var will contain an jQuery object. For example `var $star = $('#star');` otherwise regular JS vars have regular JS names :)

Comment: I am already using  Firebug and I checked before my post that post is indeed sending the correct date.  That's my frustration.

Also, I thought I was using a $ with my jQuery objects.  Where did I fail to do this?  Thanks

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I've had to take a different path because I needed to get this working which I have.  Please, no more effort on anyone's part.